# How do I collaps a mesh to have more than 4 edges overall?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to recreate the following image, but can't find a way to get the mesh to have a pentagonal/hexagonal structure. I tried different combinations to decimate the mesh, but nothing seems to work.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can decimate and use a dual mesh (geometry nodes) after that:

[image]

That won't guaranty all are hexagons or pentagons, but most should be.

Use the "triangulate" option from the decimate modifier.

Then use a "dual mesh" node in the geometry nodes setting.

It's not clear in the image if the shape is hollow or not, so I've added an optional part to make a wireframed grid.

Comment: @enats: instead of writing "thanks" which unfortunately isn't allowed/wanted here, please click on the checkmark left of lemon's answer. thx.